Does Sakurai's definition of $S$-matrix assume a particular type of scattering?
I am using Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics 3ed.
In chapter 6, Sakurai defines the $T$-matrix via the equation
$$\langle \vec{k}' \lvert U_I(t, t_0) \lvert \vec{k} \rangle = \delta_{k'k} - \frac{i}{\hbar}T_{k'k}\int_{t_0}^t dt' e^{i\omega_{k'k} t' + \epsilon t'} \tag{1}$$
where $U_I(t, t_0)$ is the exact interaction picture time evolution operator, $\lvert \vec{k} \rangle$ is a momentum eigenstate of a free particle in a box of length $L$ (we take the limit $L \to \infty$ at a later point), and $\omega_{\vec{k}'\vec{k}} = E_{\vec{k}'} - E_{\vec{k}}.$
We then compute the formal expression for the $S$-matrix
$$S_{\vec{k}'\vec{k}} = \lim_{t \to +\infty} \biggl( \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \biggl( \lim_{t_0 \to -\infty} \langle \vec{k}' \lvert U_I(t, t_0) \lvert \vec{k} \rangle\biggr) \biggr) \\ = \delta_{\vec{k}'\vec{k}} - 2\pi i \delta(E_{\vec{k}'} - E_{\vec{k}})T_{\vec{k}'\vec{k}}. \tag{2}$$
It seems that in writing down $(1)$ we have snuck in the assumption that kinetic energy of the initial state is equal to the kinetic energy of the final state. More explicitly, it is precisely from the integral in $(1)$ that we obtain the Dirac delta term in $(2)$ that quantitatively enforces this kinetic energy conservation. Surely this kinetic energy conservation is not generally true. Even in an elastic collision, the kinetic energy of the initial state need not match the kinetic energy of the final state so long as the kinetic energy of the composite system is conserved.
So, has Sakurai written down an $S$-matrix that only applies to a particular type of scattering process?

That is correct, and also a rather important assumption in QFT. It is also the reason why Haag's no-interaction theorem works: In order for this particular scheme to work, the initial state and final state and the full interacting Hamiltonian must have the same KE spectrum, in particular, even the rest masses as going into the SR $E=\sqrt{m^2+p^2}$ form must agree. We are lucky that SR even asserts that this is the correct energy form for the one-particle subspace.

But it is NOT only for purely elastic scattering. It is a general $k^\prime$ and not a rotated $k$. In particular, the length, i.e. energy corresponding to $k^\prime$ can differ from $k$, as long as total energy & momentum are conserved in the full collision process.
